# VK iOS SDK авторизация (Swift 2.0)

Tags: xcode, swift

Пробую авторизироватся ВК

```
 //MARK: VK
  func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
  {
    return VKSdk.processOpenURL(url, fromApplication: sourceApplication)
  }
```

В Plist есть

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>vkauthorize</string>
</array>
```

Сам запрос

```
@IBAction func test(sender: AnyObject)
  {
    let SCOPE = [VK_PER_FRIENDS, VK_PER_WALL, VK_PER_AUDIO, VK_PER_PHOTOS, VK_PER_NOHTTPS, VK_PER_EMAIL, VK_PER_MESSAGES];

    VKSdk.initializeWithAppId("5462514")
    VKSdk.authorize(SCOPE)
  }
```

выдает ошибку -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "vkauthorize://authorize" - error: "(null)"

прочитал что надо добавить

```
extension ViewController: VKSdkDelegate {
    func vkSdkNeedCaptchaEnter(captchaError: VKError) { }
    func vkSdkTokenHasExpired(expiredToken: VKAccessToken) { }
    func vkSdkUserDeniedAccess(authorizationError: VKError) { }
    func vkSdkShouldPresentViewController(controller: UIViewController) { }
    func vkSdkReceivedNewToken(newToken: VKAccessToken) { }
}
```

в ответ получаю ошибку Type 'TSTLogInViewController' does not conform to protocol 'VKSdkDelegate'

Соответственно VKSdk.initializeWithDelegate(self, andAppId: "46***65") тоже не работает.

Есть решение этих проблем ?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте по-простому без `extension`:

```
class TSTLogInViewController: ..., VKSdkDelegate {

    func vkSdkAccessAuthorizationFinishedWithResult(result: VKAuthorizationResult!) {
        print(result)
    }

    func vkSdkUserAuthorizationFailed() {
    }
}
```

На основе [документации](http://vkcom.github.io/vk-ios-sdk/Protocols/VKSdkDelegate.html)

Comment: ошибка с VKSdkDelegate пропала спасибо, но canOpenURL осталась.

Comment: @СвятославБойко в одном из ответов к такой ошибке на github:  `Похоже, OAuth работает только если на телефоне установлено приложение и используется forceOAuth. Во всех прочих случаях будет выдаваться указанная выше ошибка.` Попробуйте на реальном устройстве с установленным vk приложением

Comment: Спасибо, заработало... VK такое VK